# Using reCAPTCHA and auto-login with password manager

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I am using this `js`code for `reCAPTCHA`and works almost perfect.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<?php echo $config['recaptcha_site']; ?>"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo $config['recaptcha_site']; ?>', {action: 'portal_<?php echo $config['redirect']; ?>_login'}).then(function(token) {
            $('#token_1').val(token);
            $('#action_1').val('portal_<?php echo $config['redirect']; ?>_login');
        });
    });
    }, 1000);
 });
</script>
```

The submit button

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" id="login_button">Inloggen</button>
```

When a user enters all fields they can log in.
But when using a password manager like `Dashalane` the form is sent before this code is executed, resulting in a Spambot warning.

Any suggestions how to work around this?